# DialogFlow Authenticating with external application/API

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We are prototyping in dialogflow which is going well but I have what is more of a strategic question. Our app will interact with APIs in a third party system that requires user/password credentials, I am wondering if anyone can recommend an appropriate approach.

For example when I start the app in Google Assistant it *knows* who I am from my google account, this account however has no authorization for the target system - it needs an ID / password. I can prompt the user for these and they can type/say the values with which we can connect but this prompts more questions:

1. Is this secure? Clearly speaking my password isn't a great plan.
2. If this approach is reasonable is there a way to save my credentials within the app so that I don't have to enter them next time?
3. Are there other approaches to remote authentication you'd recommend? I have searched around but so far without any success.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides build in authentication options for Google Assistant. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity). If you wish to connect your Google Assistant app to your own login you want to have a look at the 0Auth or Google Sign-in + OAuth options. Depending on your requirements, one might be  a better fit.

Accountlinking is a build in solution, if you implement this you will have done it in a secure way and it is integrated with the users Google Account, so when they come back into your app they won't have to enter any credentials again.